# Burninate the [tag:region] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[region](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/region) tag seems to have a mixup of unrelated questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have retagged and removed tags for these questions.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to the specific tags and not just removing them :)